# How to search over an FS Collection?

Tags: javascript, search, meteor, collectionfs

Anybody can help me out on this? I have a group of PDF documents that I would like to be able to search. 
I've attempted use matteodem:easy-search and meteorhacks:search-source, but both of them only handle Meteor Collections and not FS. I can get both of these packages working with regular text. I just want to return the results of the search query based off the name field in the FS Collection.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] ***in your question*** so that we can reproduce the issue you're having. Please actually read the linked page and make sure that the code which you include ***in your question*** is ***minimal*** (only the code necessary to reproduce the issue, nothing more), ***complete*** (all of the code necessary to reproduce the issue, nothing less) and ***verifiable*** (we should be able to reproduce the issue using the code in your question). Without this, your question is too broad for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Install if you haven't already the reactive-var and the reactive-dict packages if you havent done that already
2. Create a reactive variable (it could also be a `Session` variable) `searchString`
3. Wrap your item display in an `{{#each chosenFiles}}` where `chosenFiles` is your helper name.
4. Create an helper `chosenFiles`  where you call your search function and provide it a cursor from your file collection.

   ```
   "chosenFiles": function() {
       return filterFiles(yourFileCollection.find());
   }
   ```
5. Create the `filterFiles` function where, basically, you get back your `searchString` and use it to filter your results, returning everything if your `searchString` is empty. Here is an example using reactive-dict:

   ```
   var pageSession = new ReactiveDict();

    filterFiles= function(cursor) {
       if(!cursor) {
           return [];
       }
       var searchString = pageSession.get("SearchString");
       var raw = cursor.fetch();

       // filter
       var filtered = [];
       if(!searchString || searchString == "") {
           filtered = raw;
       } else {
           searchString = searchString.replace(".", "\\.");
           var regEx = new RegExp(searchString, "i");
           var searchFields = ["original.name", "original.type"];
           filtered = _.filter(raw, function(item) {
               var match = false;
               _.each(searchFields, function(field) {
                   var value = (getPropertyValue(field, item) || "") + "";
                   match = match || (value && value.match(regEx));
                   if(match) {
                       return false;
                   }
               })
               return match;
           });
       }
       return filtered;
   };
   ```
6. Attach the `searchString` definition to, for instance, your `keyUp` event so that you get a reactive search.

   ```
   "keyup .yourTextBox": function(e, t) {
       var searchString = e.currentTarget.value;
       switch (e.which) {
           //pressing esc clear the textbox
           case 27:
           e.currentTarget.value = "";
           pageSession.set("SearchString", "");
           break;

           default:
           pageSession.set("SearchString", searchString);
   }
   ```

I am not 100%  sure that "original.name" is the right way to access the name field since I don't use collectionFS but it seems it is, [according to the doc](https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-CollectionFS#an-fsfile-instance)

Comment: I had to add a new field. metadata.name because original.name was not working. I'm trying to figure out why FS Collection doesn't return the value as I expected. Thank you very much for this awesome answer.